# MacBook Pro and air logic boards interchange?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, switching, motherboard

Can I interchange my logic boards from MacBook Pro  a1502 to a MacBook Air a 1466?

Answer (score 2):

**This is not possible.**

Not only are the logic board shapes and sizes entirely different, the display connectors are in a different location, the CPU and GPUs are in different locations necessitating different cooling pipes; even the I/O connectors are different (meaning the holes in the top case wouldn't match with the connectors).

<sup>MacBook Air Logic Board</sup>
[image: MacBook Air Logic Board]

<sup>MacBook Pro Logic Board</sup>
[image: MacBook Pro Logic Board]

Comment: The air has a firmware lock in place. Would exchanging the SSD with the pro allow me to use the smaller or lighter body?

Comment: The pro serial  C02PL3SAFVH7 the air serial C02TF7XNH3QD I thought the air was mid 2015, but produced in 2017. Make a difference?

Comment: I did a bit of research and the mid 2013 through 2015 MBA SSDs are interchangeable with the 2013-2015 MBP SSDs